# create a excel search engine using vba and filters

Tags: excel, vba, search

I am trying to create a search engine using vba to filter my rows based on a value entered into a cell/my search bar.

```
    Sub DateFilter()
    'hide dialogs
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'filter for records that have June 11, 2012 in column 3
    ActiveSheet.Range("A5:C30").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=ActiveSheet.Range("A5").Value
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This macro runs when a user hits my search button and will filter my rows based on the cell value in my cell A5.

However whilst the code is filtering it is showing the wrong result.

I have the following layout in excel:

```
A           B            C
White       XXX          London
Black       ZZZ          Manchester
Gold        TTT          England
Silver      FFFF         Scotland
```

If I type in my cell A5 the word White it will show silver?

Can someone please show me where I am going wrong? Thanks

Comment: Rather than **A5**, try using a cell that is **outside** the filtered area.

Answer (score 0):

As Gary's Student commented, you're currently filtering your rows based on a cell value *inside* your rows.

Instead of this, filter it based on a value outside, like D1. Then you can put whatever you like into the D1 cell for your filter.